# I need to create a diagonal matrix where the diagonal elements are a vector

Tags: matlab

The vector should look something like,

```
[1 2 3 0 0 0
 0 1 2 3 0 0
 0 0 1 2 3 0
 0 0 0 1 2 3];
```

I know the vector ([1 2 3]) that I wish to 'paste' along the diagonal but I do not know the size of the array so the number of rows would need to be determined by a variable N.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`spdiags`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/spdiags.html) to set the diagonals and have the desired shape:

```
n = 4;
A = full(spdiags(ones(n,1)*[1,2,3],[0,1,2],n,n+2));
```

This returns:

```
A =

   1   2   3   0   0   0
   0   1   2   3   0   0
   0   0   1   2   3   0
   0   0   0   1   2   3
```

Answer (score 4):

It's a bit crude, but possible to construct the desired matrix as toeplitz:

```
a = [1 2 3]; 
toeplitz([a(1); zeros(length(a),1)],[a(:); zeros(length(a),1)])
```

with answer:

```
ans =

 1     2     3     0     0     0
 0     1     2     3     0     0
 0     0     1     2     3     0
 0     0     0     1     2     3
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use 2D-convolution:

```
v = [1 2 3];
N = 4;
result = conv2(v, eye(N))
```